# Salvar Pedido - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Quero fazer um simples ecommerce no meu site, baseado nesta pergunta: 
[Implementação de Carrinho de Compras em ASP.NET MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40857/implementa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-carrinho-de-compras-em-asp-net-mvc)

Porém, estou com dúvida na hora de fazer duas coisas:
1º Salvar os dados na tabela Pedido e ItemPedido, com alguns dados provenientes da session carrinho.
2º Como fazer para remover os itens do carrinho? Para adicionar está tudo certo, mas não estou conseguindo remover.

Como eu disse, estou fazendo de acordo com o link acima, então meu código é praticamente igual. Seguem eles:

```
public ActionResult AdicionarCarrinho(int id)
{

    Pedido carrinho = Session["Carrinho"] != null ? (Pedido)Session["Carrinho"] : new Pedido();

    var produto= db.Produto.Find(id);

    if produto!= null)
    {
        var itemPedido= new ItemPedido();
        itemPedido.Produto = produto;
        itemPedido.Qtd = 1;

        if (carrinho.ItemPedido.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IdProduto== produto.IdProduto) != null)
        {
            carrinho.ItemPedido.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IdProduto== produto.IdProduto).Qtd += 1;
        }

        else
        {
            carrinho.ItemPedido.Add(itemPedido);
        }



        carrinho.ValorTotal = carrinho.ItemPedido.Select(i => i.Produto).Sum(d => d.Preco);

        Session["Carrinho"] = carrinho;
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Carrinho");
}

public ActionResult Carrinho()
{
    Pedido carrinho = Session["Carrinho"] != null ? (Pedido)Session["Carrinho"] : new Pedido();

    return View(carrinho);
}
```

E as tabelas no banco de dados:

```
Produto:
IdProduto
Nome
Preco

ItemPedido:
Id
IdProduto
IdPedido

Pedido:
IdPedido
DtPedido
StatusPedido
IdUsuario
DtPagamento
Valor
```

Comment: Mostre seu código, como você está tentando fazer? Está ocorrendo algum erro? Caso positivo insira o erro na sua pergunta para tentarmos ajudar. O título é "Salvar Pedido - ASP.NET MVC" mas sua dúvida é sobre como remover?

Comment: Qual a tecnologia que você está usando para salvar os dados? Coloque os fontes, para a gente tentar lhe ajudar.

Comment: Bem Guilherme, já que você é novato na linguagem e quer aprender, primeiramente vá no site oficial do [Asp.Net](http://asp.net/mvc) pra aprender mais sobre a linguagem. Como o tutorial que vou passar aqui é muito grande vou passar o link por aqui e não por resposta e você aprenda. Resumindo: É um projeto de e-comerce que inclusive tem carrinho de compras. Então [dê uma olhada](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1) e aprenda !

Comment: Já tentou `Session["Carrinho"] = null` ? Se o problema é limpar o carrinho basta setar a `Session` para nula.

Comment: carrinho.ItemPedido.Clear()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estou supondo que, ao exibir seu carrinho, `ItemPedido` já tenha um Id preenchido por você. Ou seja, haveria de ter uma alteração aqui:

```
public ActionResult AdicionarCarrinho(int id)
{
    Pedido carrinho = Session["Carrinho"] != null ? (Pedido)Session["Carrinho"] : new Pedido();

    var produto= db.Produto.Find(id);

    if produto!= null)
    {
        var itemPedido= new ItemPedido();
        itemPedido.Id = // Coloque aqui um Id
        itemPedido.Produto = produto;
        itemPedido.Qtd = 1;
    }

    ...
}
```

Só que não recomendo o uso de Ids inteiros nessa parte. O ideal seria um Id gerado (como um [`Guid`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identificador_%C3%9Anico_Global), por exemplo. [A Microsoft tem essa estrutura que o uso é transparente no ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx).

Ou seja, seu *Model* ficaria assim:

```
public class ItemPedido 
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ItemPedidoId { get; set; }
    public Guid ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public Guid PedidoId { get; set; }

    public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }
    public virtual Pedido Pedido { get; set; }
}
```

E o método no *Controller*:

```
public ActionResult AdicionarCarrinho(int id)
{

    Pedido carrinho = Session["Carrinho"] != null ? (Pedido)Session["Carrinho"] : new Pedido();

    var produto= db.Produto.Find(id);

    if produto!= null)
    {
        var itemPedido= new ItemPedido();
        itemPedido.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        itemPedido.Produto = produto;
        itemPedido.Qtd = 1;
    }

    ...
}
```

Para excluir agora fica mais simples. Crie mais uma `Action` no *Controller*:

```
public ActionResult ExcluirItem(Guid id) 
{
    var carrinho = Session["Carrinho"] != null ? (Pedido)Session["Carrinho"] : new Pedido();
    var itemExclusao = carrinho.ItemPedido.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ItemPedidoId == id);
    carrinho.ItemPedido.Remove(itemExclusao);

    Session["Carrinho"] = carrinho;
    return RedirectToAction("Carrinho");
}
```

Para salvar (estou supondo pelo menos Entity Framework 6 para esta lógica funcionar):

```
public ActionResult SalvarCarrinho() 
{
    var carrinho = Session["Carrinho"] != null ? (Pedido)Session["Carrinho"] : new Pedido();

    contexto.Pedidos.Add(carrinho);
    contexto.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Carrinho");
}
```

Comment: quando clico em finalizar carrinho dá o seguinte erro: "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiples instances of IEntityChangeTracker".e uma segunda dúvida quando eu salvo o pedido, automaticamente eu salvo na tabela itempedido tbm? pois preciso exibir o pedido junto com os dados do item pedido.

Comment: Se você fez como na resposta, e é Entity Framework 6, o contexto salva o pedido e seus respectivos ítens. Quanto ao problema, isto é escopo de uma pergunta em específico.

Comment: po cara quer que eu abra outra pergunta relacionada a esta?

Comment: Sim, por favor.

Comment: já abri uma nova pergunta.