# Erro ao salvar dados de uma sessão no banco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de vendas. Segue o link:
[Salvar Pedido - ASP.NET MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42735/salvar-pedido-asp-net-mvc/42804)

Porém ao finalizar a compra e salvar os dados no banco, eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker"

Como posso resolver isso?

```
public ActionResult SalvarCarrinho() 
{
    var carrinho = Session["Carrinho"] != null ? (Pedido)Session["Carrinho"] : new Pedido();

    contexto.Pedidos.Add(carrinho);
    contexto.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Carrinho");
}
```

Dá erro nesta linha:

```
 contexto.Pedidos.Add(carrinho);
```

Código completo do *Controller*:

```
public ActionResult AdicionarCarrinho(int id)
{
    Pedido carrinho = Session["Carrinho"] != null ? (Pedido)Session["Carrinho"] : new Pedido();

    var produto= db.Produto.Find(id);

    if (produto != null)
    {
        var itemPedido = new ItemPedido();
        itemPedido.Produto = produto;
        itemPedido.Qtd = 1;


        if (carrinho.ItemPedido.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IdProduto == produto.IdProduto) != null)
        {
            carrinho.ItemPedido.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IdProduto == produto.IdProduto).Qtd += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            carrinho.ItemPedido.Add(itemPedido);
        }



        carrinho.ValorTotal = carrinho.ItemPedido.Select(i => i.Pedido).Sum(d => d.Preco);

        Session["Carrinho"] = carrinho;
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Carrinho");
}

public ActionResult Carrinho()
{
    Pedido carrinho = Session["Carrinho"] != null ? (Pedido)Session["Carrinho"] : new Pedido();

    return View(carrinho);
}


public ActionResult Remover(int id)
{
    var carrinho = Session["Carrinho"] != null ? (Pedido)Session["Carrinho"] : new Pedido();
    var itemExclusao = carrinho.ItemPedido.FirstOrDefault(i => i.IdItemPedido == id);
    carrinho.ItemPedido.Remove(itemExclusao);

    Session["Carrinho"] = carrinho;
    return RedirectToAction("Carrinho");
}

public ActionResult FinalizarCarrinho()
{
    var carrinho = Session["Carrinho"] != null ? (Pedido)Session["Carrinho"] : new Pedido();

    var id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["IdUsuario"]);
    var usuario = db.Usuario.FirstOrDefault(u => u.IdUsuario == id);
    carrinho.DtPedido = DateTime.Now;
    carrinho.Usuario = usuario;
    carrinho.StatusPedido = "esperando pagamento";
    carrinho.TipoPag = "boleto";
    db.Pedido.Add(carrinho);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Carrinho");
}
```

Comment: Agora você coloca o código que está dando problema no corpo da pergunta, por favor.

Comment: ta ai o código.

Comment: Acredito que seja o fato de haver mais de um contexto em algum lugar. O código não é claro quanto a isso. Como está a declaração dos contextos?

Comment: você quer ver as classes pedido etc?

Comment: Não, eu quero o código do *Controller*.

Comment: Não utilizei a guid pois o IdItemPedido é gerado sozinho pelo banco de dados.

Comment: já atualizei com oque você pediu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não lembro se disse isso em outra resposta, mas possivelmente a causa do problema é isto:

```
var itemPedido = new ItemPedido();
itemPedido.Produto = design; // Aqui você definiu um Produto (e de forma errada)
itemPedido.Qtd = 1;
itemPedido.IdProduto = produto.IdProduto; // Então aqui vai dar problema
```

Considerando ainda que você tomou a decisão de utilizar Id como inteiro sequencial, a chance de confundir o Entity Framework é grande. Explico:

Ao definir uma Id desta forma:

```
itemPedido.IdProduto = produto.IdProduto;
```

Você está forçando num objeto **não mapeado** em contexto uma Id de um objeto **mapeado** em contexto. E aqui:

```
itemPedido.Produto = design;
```

Você está colocando um outro objeto (que eu não sei de onde veio, porque possivelmente é uma colagem de outra resposta que eu dei) que eu não sei se está mapeado no contexto ou não. Fazendo isto, você está basicamente criando um `produto` que não existe (ou pelo menos o contexto entende assim), porque é a Id de um objeto com o conteúdo de outro objeto.

Neste caso, preencher `itemPedido.IdProduto` é **totalmente desnecessário**, visto que você já está preenchendo `itemPedido.Produto`. Deve-se evitar preencher um Id de chave estrangeira diretamente, pois o Entity Framework pode entender que é um objeto novo (muito provável que seja este o seu problema) e inserir no banco de dados algo que não deve.

Mesma coisa pra este código:

```
carrinho.IdUsuario = Convert.ToInt32(Session["IdUsuario"]);
```

O correto é você selecionar o usuário e atribuir o objeto de `Usuario` ao carrinho, para que o Entity Framework entenda de onde esse usuário veio:

```
var usuarioId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["IdUsuario"]);
var usuario = db.Usuarios.FirstOrDefault(u => u.IdUsuario == usuarioId);
carrinho.Usuario = usuario;
```

---

**EDIT**

Baseado nos comentários, aparentemente os objetos que vão para a sessão estão guardando a referência de um contexto que não existe mais, então antes de inserir produtos no pedido, faça o seguinte:

```
var produto = db.Produto.Find(id);
db.Entry(produto).State = EntityState.Detached;

if (produto != null)
{
    var itemPedido = new ItemPedido();
    itemPedido.Produto = produto;
    itemPedido.Qtd = 1;

    ...
```

Isto garante que você estará trabalhando com objetos destacados de contexto.

Pra salvar, você precisa recolocar os objetos no contexto:

```
public ActionResult FinalizarCarrinho()
{
    var carrinho = Session["Carrinho"] != null ? (Pedido)Session["Carrinho"] : new Pedido();

    var id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["IdUsuario"]);
    var usuario = db.Usuario.FirstOrDefault(u => u.IdUsuario == id);

    foreach (var itemPedido in carrinho.ItemPedido) {
        db.Produtos.Attach(itemPedido.Produto);
    }

    carrinho.DtPedido = DateTime.Now;
    carrinho.Usuario = usuario;
    carrinho.StatusPedido = "esperando pagamento";
    carrinho.TipoPag = "boleto";
    db.Pedido.Add(carrinho);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Carrinho");
}
```

Não testei essa solução, mas creio que deve funcionar.

Comment: Retirei as outras linhas, e deixei somente essa: itemPedido.Produto = produto mas continua dando o mesmo erro. Vou postar como está o codigo atualmente.

Comment: Atualizei da forma que você indicou, mas o erro continua.

Comment: Ainda tenho uma dúvida: onde fica e como você inicializa esse contexto? A impressão que dá é que ele está sendo inicializado N vezes, que é o que o erro diz.

Comment: Não sei se eu entendi muito bem. Mas eu chamo as classes do banco de dados através dessa linha que eu defini no inicio do controller: private Entidades db = new Entidades();

Comment: Acho que já sei o que é. Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: @GuilhermeVinicius Veja agora.

Comment: Esses "métodos" attach e dettach tem que fazer alteração nas classes, porque ele não tá reconhecendo e da erro nessa linha?

Comment: Verdade. Veja agora.

Comment: cara o attach ele achou mas o dettach não.

Comment: @GuilhermeVinicius Mudaram a sintaxe. Use `db.Entry(produto).State = EntityState.Detached;`.

Comment: Agora funcionou. Muito obrigado mesmo, salvou minha pele aqui.